# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent sospicious behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, twitter-fabric

I have an app in production and in the last 24 hrs I received something like 50 crashes from a single user (3-4 per hour).

Fabric marks the device type as "sdk" and the OS version is always 4.1.1.

This is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms&pcampaignid=gcore_8487000--- flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:843)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

There is no sign of my package name, looks like the app is trying to open an internal intent of which I have no control over.

Could that be an user/bot without Google Play Store?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so what is happening is that the device on which your app is crashing does not contain any app to handle an implicit intent sent from your app.

What this means is, somewhere in your code, you might have sent an implicit intent with a View action on it. Now, when this is run on a device, which does not contain any Activity to resolve a view intent, it crashes. You should always check whether an intent sent from your code, can be handled by other apps on the device, before starting the Activity. Something like:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

// Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

As you see in the above code, the resolveActivity() method is being called before starting the activity. If android does not find any apps capable of handling your intent, it would return null and then perhaps you can put an else condition and handle this situation gracefully. What i gather from the logs is that you might have sent an intent, with an ACTION_VIEW to maybe view some item from your app on any other app the system finds capable.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html